# Responsiveness issue for smart search extension's live search drop down in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: html, css, opencart2.x

I have added an extension called "Smart Search" in my open cart 2.0.1.1 , I need the drop down containing the results for live search to be responsive on every device, how can i do that using css?

The link for the extension is : 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `Media Queries` and it solved the issue of responsiveness on mobile view